# Dryer only getting 120v

Tags: electrical, dryer, 240v

There is something wrong with my dryer/electrical and I just can't figure out what it is. Is this a dryer issue or an electrical issue? I just need to know who I should call to fix it. I did all I'm really able to I believe.

Okay, my dryer is rather new (a little over a year old) and it'll either heat or turn on, but not both. I tested it and it only gets 120v instead of 220v. One side gets no power, one side gets 120. Together they get 120. The weird thing though is if I flip the dryer cord around it will turn on, but again it won't heat. So only one side is working.

I replaced the cord and the outlet, but it still did the same thing. I can't test the breaker because I just don't know how and it's covered up and I don't want to deal with it.

This is a three prong outlet as well. I also did get it to heat/power for awhile but then it stopped working again after a week or so. The breaker was also tripped one of these times.

Comment: why would you replace the power plug and the power cord without first measuring the voltage at the plug?

Comment: My guess is the breaker is bad since only one side is working.  You should call an electrician or find a friend with knowledge.

Comment: shoot us a photo of the breaker panel.  Also what points are you measuring on the socket? Between the slots?   Or between a slot and the L shaped neutral?